# Анимация изменения Value в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

Учусь писать на React,
 Существует ли способ, средствами React анимировать смену положения input type="range"

То есть после того как его выставили и отпустили, он меняет свое значение скажем на центральное

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите плагин react-addons-css-transition-group 
https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html
Нет смысла изобретать свой велосипед.